# Google analitics wrong visitors number

Tags: google-analytics

I've found some info about this issue in the internet but nothing really helpful.
I'm using Google Analytics on my page and have the code added properly before `</head>` on every page.

I also don't have any JS errors in the code.

I've added small php counter to my page also, it is tracking every page opening.

And for example for yesterday I have 6000 page openings when Google shows only 700... (I'm checking every page opening not visits).

Why are these counts different? I guess my PHP counter is adding also some bots visits etc, but it shouldn't be that many.

Is there something I should check here? Change some setting in Google Analytics maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you can do is when making the tracking (throw you php counter), to save the referer, and after one day check how many of those visits are crawlers. Anyway this is only for you, cause GA is the best and most accurate tool for website visitors tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Most counters track visits, and not visitors. Check the Google Analytics Visit count to compare. Also make sure you don't have any Segments applied that would be filtering your count.